# Load file into Map keep original line order

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collections, treemap

I need to load a lookup CSV file that will be used to apply some regex rules (key, value) to strings. These rules need to be applied in the order they appear in the file.

Loading it into a Map doesn't guarantee the order is kept.

Is there a way to load the CSV file into a structure like a TreeMap (or other) while maintaining the file row order?

I would like to avoid to hardcode an index/key directly into the file (that would be a possible solution, but would make maintaining the CSV dictionaries harder). Perhaps there's a way to generate an index "on the fly" while loading it?

```scala
val vMap = sparkSession.read.option( "header", true ).csv( pPath )
      .rdd.map(x => (x.getString(0), x.getString(1)))  
      .collectAsMap()
```

So having some "rules" like :

```
(ab)cd, $1

(ab)cde, $1

(ab),$1

(ab)cdfgh,$1

(ff)gt,$1
```

I would like in the end to be able to have a collection that I could iterate upon, following that same order, preferably with a `foreach` method. What I get now is a random Map that will be iterated each time in a different order.

Edit: forgot to mention i am using **scala version 2.11.12,** which came packed into the latest spark release.

**Possible solution** (based on user6337 answer)

So reading the answer and thinkering with it, got to this piece of code.

```scala
var myMap = new mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, String]()
val vList = sparkSession.read.option( "header", true ).csv( pPath )
      .collect().map( t => myMap += ((t(0).toString, t(1).toString)))

myMap.foreach( x => println(x._1+ " - "+x._2)
```

My new concern is if this reading of a Dataframe is enough to guarantee file line ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LinkedHashMap, which preserves the order in which the items were added to the LinkedHashMap.

Here is some example code

```
import scala.collection.mutable

object Main extends App {

  val myList = List(("1", "a"),("2","b"),("3","c"),("4","d"))
  println(myList)

  val myMap = mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, String]()

  myMap.addAll(myList)

  myMap.foreach(println)
}
```

Running this code prints

```
List((1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d))
(1,a)
(2,b)
(3,c)
(4,d)
```

which is what you want.

So first convert your data into a collection like a List or a Vector, and then load it into your mutable LinkedHashMap using addAll. Order will be preserved when you use map or foreach on the LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I got my function to return a List. Unfortunately, I take a look at the documentation os my scala version and it dosen't have the addAll method. 
So I rewrited my read function to make the mapping from a List to a LinkHashedList, seemed to work, will update the Question with this possible solution.

One more thing, researching about this I read that the Dataframe also dosent guarantee file line ordering. I wonder fi theres a risk that while reading and passing the data along to the Hashmap some data may eventually get placed in the wrong place

Comment: I think i will mark your answer as the solution, since it was pretty close :)  Also I do not have enough rep yet to vote.